# Intersections of infinitely many elements of non principal filter.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $X$ be some infinite set. Also let $\mathscr{F}(X)$ be a non principal filter on $X$ with infinitely many elements in it. Now I attempted to show that $\mathscr{F}(X)$ isn't closed under infinite intersections of it's elements.

**MY ATTEMPT:-**

Assume that $\mathscr{F}(X)= \{A_1,A_2....\}$ are all elements of $\mathscr{F}$. I will split it into two parts,

$(1)$ I will show that intersections of all elements of $\mathscr{F}$ is an empty set.

*Proof:-* We shall proceed by contradiction. We will assume that intersection of all elements is some non empty set.
Let,
$$B= A_{1} \cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}...$$
It's not hard to see that as a consequence of that intersections, $B\in\mathscr{F}$. So by the axioms of filters,
$$B \subseteq N \subseteq X \implies N\in \mathscr{F}$$ all such $N$ will be in $\mathscr{F}$. So $\mathscr{F}$ is a principle filter generated by $N$. Which contradicts the fact that $\mathscr{F}$ is a non principal filter.

$(2)$ I will show that intersections of a subset of $\mathscr{F}$ with infinitely many members in it  is also an empty set.

*proof:-* We will again proceed by contradiction. Let, $G\subset \mathscr{F}$ and intersections all elements of $G$ is $D$. So again it's not hard to show that $D\in\mathscr{F}$. Also Let $X\setminus G=\{H_1,H_2...\}$. By case-1, the intersections of all elements from a non principal filter is an empty.
$$G\cap H_1\cap H_2...=\phi$$
So $\phi\in\mathscr{F}$. And $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{P}(X)$, which then will be a principle filter generated by $\phi$. Contradicting our assumption.

**My question:-**

$(1)$- Is my attempt correct? If not please provide some counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider $\cal F$ as the set of all co-finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ such that $42$ is an element of that subset. Easily, this is a filter, and it is also non-principal, since the intersection of all the sets is $\{42\}$ which is finite and therefore not in $\cal F$.

Instead you simply need to use the fact that a filter $\cal F$ is principal if and only if $\bigcap\cal F\in F$. Since $\cal F$ is infinite, that's pretty much the end of the proof here.

Comment: I would downvote that answer. The collection of infinite elements with $42$ in it, will be a principal filter.

Comment: @RAHUL: How can it be principal? $\{42\}$ is not infinite. But okay.

Comment: ,Well, I think it's principle filter @Asaf Karagila , because we considered all supersets of $\{49\}$. Even power set is also a principle filter generated by $\phi$.

Comment: @RAHUL: There is a definition for "principal filter", if you apply it to $\cal F$, you will easily see that it is not principal. Principal *filter* is not "generated by a single point", it means $\bigcap\cal F\in F$. Now, since all the elements of $\cal F$ are infinite, how can $\{42\}$ be in that collection?

Comment: (As an unrelated note, in most cases, filters are required to be *proper*, meaning $\varnothing$ is not an element of the filter. In another note, *principal* and not *principle*, and in a final note, $\varnothing$ and not $\phi$.)

Comment: Well, op mentioned that $\mathscr{F}$ consists of infinitely many elements. Not that each element has infinite cardinality

Comment: @RAHUL: So now the problem is that there are only finitely many infinite sets which contain $42$? I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131458/discussion-between-rahul-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Let's not. I have to leave the office now. Read my answer *carefully* and you'll see that it is not wrong.

Comment: Well @Asaf Karagila, your answer is giving a positive sense. But I am really confused, please I request to elaborate or let me know where the mistake is.